# Is a norm of a vector of distances itself a metric on vectors?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose I have $\vec x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\vec y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ and a sequence of metrics $d_i$ for $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ that are used for the $i$th component.

Consider a vector of distances, $\vec d (\vec x, \vec y)$ where the $i$th component of $\vec d (\vec x, \vec y)$ is given by $d_i(x_i,y_i)$.

Now to further aggregate the distances. Some aggregation function $\alpha : [0,\infty)^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ could be considered. More narrowly there may be choices of aggregation functions that composed on our distance vector would give a distance function on the vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

$\alpha (d_1(x_1, y_1), \ldots, d_n(x_n, y_n))$

> **Example**
> Take $d_i$ to be the taxicab distance, and $\alpha$ to be the $p$th root of the sum of powers of $p$ of its inputs.
> $$||\vec x - \vec y||_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i}^n |x_i-y_i|^p}$$
> is a metric.

> **Question**
> If $\alpha$ is a norm, will a norm on a vector of metrics always produce a metric between the vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ assuming they are vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: This is true when the norm $\alpha : [0,\infty)^n \to [0,\infty)$ is monotone in each coordinate (this seems necessary for the triangle inequality).  My gut says it's false in general, but I haven't found a counterexample yet.